# Why does Photoshop CC 2015 auto-start when I boot Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-photoshop

I recently installed Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 and it auto-starts when I boot or re-start Windows 10 Anniversary OS. Is it a Windows problem or a Photoshop problem. My old Photoshop 7 never did this.

- I have checked [WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/?__c=1) and can't seem to find it in the start-up program list.
- I don't see anything in the Photoshop options either.

Any suggestions? Anybody else have the same problem?

Comment: Try opening 'run' (press Win+R) and entering `shell:startup`. This takes you to a folder that contains shortcuts to programs that are automatically started after logging in. Check if there's a shortcut to Photoshop in there.

Comment: Thanks to you and jamjet147 below I was able to fix the problem. I appreciate the leads from you both.

Comment: What was the solution? Please accept the answer or post a new answer so future people with the same problem can easily find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

*[Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)* is a free tool from SysInternals (now part of Microsoft) that shows virtually *everything* that starts automatically (e.g. in the Startup folder, from the Registry Run and RunOnce keys etc.). *Autoruns* also allows you to temporarily disable or completely remove an entry, and you can search for entries by name, publisher, path etc.

[image: Autoruns from SysInternals]